# Please solve this loader failed

Tags: reactjs

My project was built by Laravel and React.js.
And I used pdf-dist.js and I compiled it successfully.
The project is working well in web browser of PC.
But it's not working in Smart phone because of below code.

```
getJSActions() {
    return this._jsActionsPromise ||= 
    this._transport.getPageJSActions(this._pageIndex);
}
```

Comment: Check the compatibility here :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#:~:text=sec%2Dassignment%2Doperators-,Browser%20compatibility,-Report%20problems%20with